# how to upload a video file into database in php

Tags: php, sql

i want to upload video from my computer to my website. already i add videos from other sites using links of video and using my own custom thumbnail for that video if i want.
but now i want to upload video from my computer to database. and then display the video on my site. but i have no idea how to do it.

i'm using this code for uploading video from my computer and also using this code from uploading video link from another site. but its not working for uploading video from my computer.

please anyone can help me with example. i really appreciated your struggle. thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['video'])) {
    $video_url = $_POST['video_url'];
    $thumbnail_code = end(explode('/', $video_url));
    if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '') {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)
        ) {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                    $imagenames = "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO abc (video_url,thumbnail_code,images)
                VALUES('$video_url','$thumbnail_code','$imagenames')";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO abc (video_url,thumbnail_code)
                VALUES('$video_url','$thumbnail_code')";
    }
    $query = $conn->query($sql) or die ('no table found');
    if ($query) {
        $msg = "Video Added Successfully";
        header("location:video.php?msg=$msg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You upload the **Path** of the uploaded video, not the video to your database.

- Upload the video - using this code .
- Save the video infromation to your database and  **the video's path**.

```
 "../img/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this with more example. or editing my code. its really help full for me.

Comment: Basically he means you upload the video file and instead of putting that into the database you put the url of where the real video file is stored into the database as a pointer so when someone access the database they receive the url and can then download or find the video

Comment: but my video is in my computer. so how can i put url in database? -- #Dean219